# Delayed Job: job cannot be created for non-persisted record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

I am using carrierwave to upload files to amazon S3 and the delayed_job_activerecord gem.

I have a function where I generate an xlsx file and upload it to amazon S3 but I get this error :

> job cannot be created for non-persisted record: #<Xlsxfiles id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, xlsxfile: nil>

Xlsxfiles is the uploader

Here is my function:

```
def generate_xlsx(content)

    temp_file = Tempfile.new(['users','.xlsx'])
    ToXls::Writer.new(content, {:columns => [:name,:address],
        :headers => ["name","address"]}).write_io(temp_file)

    temp_file.rewind
    file = File.open(temp_file)
    #self.xlsxfile = file
    self.xlsxfile.store!(file)#
    #self.write_carrierwave_identifier
    self.save!

  end

  handle_asynchronously :generate_xlsx
```

and here is where i call the funciton

```
 def index
        @users = User.all.page(params[:page]).per(10)
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.xls {

                s = Xlsxfiles.new
                s.generate_xlsx(@users)

                redirect_to :back
                }
            end
        end
```

Without the delayed job my function works and uploads the file to S3,
but when I use delayed job, the job executes before the activerecord is saved, any solution?

Comment: Have you tried moving `self.save!` up a few lines to happen before uploading?

Comment: Don't you need to be looking at the code that calls generate_xlsx rather than its implementation?

Comment: Nick Veys, that doesn't work! Frederick Cheung i will edit my post with the code that calls the generate_xlsx !

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, you need to save the `Xlsxfile` instance *before* you call `generate_xlsx` on it. Try the following:

```
s = Xlsxfiles.create
s.generate_xlsx(@users)
```

You might need to adjust validations on `Xlsxfile` so that they allow saving empty records.

Comment: i got this error  >  can't dump anonymous module: #<Module:0x007fe7ced84a10> when i use create!

Comment: Try this: `@users = User.all.page(params[:page]).per(10).to_a` -- without calling `to_a`, `@users` is an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, and not an array of `User` models, and delayed_job might have problems serializing an `ActiveRecord::Relation`.